# Which SQL Server performance condition DB alert can be used to find "RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE" waits?

Tags: sql-server, alerts, waits

I'm trying 2 SQL Server Alerts:
SQL Server:Memory Manager / Memory Grants Pending / Waits in progress / rises above / Value: 5

SQL Server:wait Statistics / Memory grant queue waits / Waits in progress / rises above / Value: 5

This is SQL Server 2008 R2.   (I know were building DEV env now for 2019)
8 cores, 50 GB memory server, 25GB Max SQL memory size - soon to be 35GB, 3500-4000 sessions, 350GB DB/250GB TLOG - Manufacturing lines monitoring Application.  Many parallel queries due to 1 billion row table.  (I know... purge and archive is part of upgrade)